# PHP - Export Altitude (z dimension) from a geometry postgis position

Tags: php, geometry, postgis, wkb

I have a 3D Point like

> 01010000A0E6100000075F984C153C4A40705F07CE199141400000000000000000

and I want to export x,y and z dimensions from it using PHP. I find [GeoPHP library](https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP) in my searches and seems that it supports 3D points.

I used library like it's examples:

```
$wkb_reader = new WKB();
$geometry = $wkb_reader->read('01010000A0E6100000075F984C153C4A40705F07CE199141400000000000000000',TRUE);

print $geometry->getX() . " , " . $geometry->getY() . " , " . $geometry->getZ();
```

But no getZ() function is defined :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Point::getZ()
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Looks like Stable 3D support is not available yet. [#53](https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/pull/53), [#54](https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/pull/54), [#91](https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/issues/91)

Comment: @elavarasanlee You are right. thanks

Comment: If you have SQL access, use `SELECT ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom), ST_Z(geom) FROM ...` to get these.

Comment: @MikeT I used this approach and it works but I want to handle it PHP side not SQL side.

Comment: ["geoPHP only supports 2-dimensional space"](https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/blob/d7e099a8f4ce23db1d0b1840b1ec984c5d208fb4/lib/geometry/Geometry.class.php#L337-L340), so you will need to either modify the library or use a different approach

Comment: and what can be that different library or approach? how to modify this library?

Comment: you can modify the library yourself (it has a BSD license) or sponsor a developer to add this enhancement .. so this option isn't easy or fast since it would probably take weeks to do. Your best option is to use a different approach.